# Every regular surface can be covered by an atlas surface patches with $E=1$ and $F=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

Want to prove the following statement

> Every regular surface can be covered by an atlas surface patches with $E=1$ and $F=0$

I already know two facts:

1. Gauss lemma: For any regular surface $p\in S$, the first fundamental form of the surface patch $\sigma$ for normal polar coordinates at $p$ has the form $F_1 = dr^2+Gd\theta^2$ (note that $\sigma:(0,\epsilon)\times (0,2\pi)\to S$ where $\epsilon$ is a radius of normal nbd of $p$ and $\sigma(r,\theta) = \text{exp}_p((rcos\theta)e_1+(rsin\theta)e_2)$ where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ are an orthonormal basis of $T_pS$.)
2. If $S$ is a regular surface and $p\in S$, the there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $p\in S$ and a single $\delta>0$ that serves as the radius of a valid normal neighborhood of each point of $W$.

So anyway, most of the result follows form Gauss lemma but the problem is that such normal polar coordinate doesn't cover $p$. But by the fact 2, for sufficiently close $q\in S$ to $p$, I can take a normal nbd so that $p$ can be covered by a normal polar surface patch. And I think this extends the normal polar surface patch of $p$. Is my argument valid?

Comment: You raise a valid point. I'm not sure how the normal coordinate neighborhood at nearby $q$ *extends* the one we had at $p$. But their union certainly covers both $p$ and $q$. ... I think it's handy to think of polar coordinates with $r\ge 0$ and just have it fail to be a diffeomorphism at $r=0$; it's actually the "blow up" of the origin, with a point for each direction at the origin. For computations it will ordinarily not affect things to think on this blown-up chart.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I thought the problem is whether it actually extends the one at $p$. Then how can I cover $p$? Or for surface patch at $p$, we just take another surface patch at $q$ near $p$ so that it covers $p$ (but not $q$)?

Comment: I already answered this.

Comment: @TedShifrin You mean think of polar coordinates with $r\geq 0$? But as you said it fails to be a diffeomorphism... I'm not good at English so actually hard to understand.